# Stata twoway line graph showing more than one value

Tags: line, stata

I want to compare the black male prison population for Texas and the average black male prison population for the rest of the US over a period of 15 years. I created a new variable `mean_prison` to get the US average over each year using `egen` (`bmprison` is the variable for black male prison population):

`egen mean_prison = mean(bmprison) if state ~= "Texas", by(year)`

Browsing through the data, each year has the same value for `mean_prison` which is what I want, but the output of `line mean_prison year` shows different values for some of the years. Can someone explain what is happening? I have attached the graph.
[image]

Comment: I guess you just omitted the `sort` option.

Comment: can you share the data or create a MWE?

Comment: @Lucas's advice is good, but I am fairly confident in my guess. The spurious connection between the last value and the first is not a bug. Stata is doing what you told it to do, connect the data in the order of observations. It's just that somehow your data are out of order or repeated. and you need to insist with `sort` that order on `year` is what matters.